# importing dart code from other projects

Tags: dart, dart-pub

****** This question is edited and cleaned up some ******

I have two projects and I want to use code from one in the other; I seem to be having trouble putting the code in the right directory structure to make the import statements work.

Both projects are created and managed exclusively from the Dart Editor on a Mac, if that makes any differences.

**Project Directory Structures**
Project 1: a command line app which contains the code I want to share in the following directory structure:

```dart
/dart/command_line_app
    /lib
      shared_library.dart
    /bin
      command_line_app.dart
```

Project 2: a web app which wants to import the code in shared_libary.dart

```dart
/dart/web_application
    /packages
    /web
        web_application.dart
```

In the file shared_libary.dart, I declare it to be a library can create a simple class that provides output when instantiated:

```dart
library shared_library;

class ShareMe
{
  ShareMe()
  {
    print("Hello, ShareMe");
  }
}
```

This compiles, and works inside the command_line project: command_line_app.dart has the following:

```dart
import 'package:command_line_app/shared_library.dart';

void main() {
  ShareMe shareMe = new ShareMe();

  print("Hello, World!");
}
```

This imports the code runs, printing both "Hello Share Me," and Hello World.

**THE PROBLEM**
I want to instantiate the ShareMe class inside web_application.dart. I'd thought I could do that by putting in the same import statement I put in my command_line code:

```dart
import 'package:command_line_app/shared_library.dart';
```

But, when I put the same import into the web_appliation, it gets the error

```dart
Target of URI does not exist 'package:command_line_app/shared_library.dart'
```

**Other Things I've Tried**
I was certain I'd solved the problem when I cntrl-Clicked properties on Web_application and selected Project References.

It brings up a window allowing me to select command_line_app with a check box, but when I do, I get an error:

```dart
Could not set the project description for 'web_application' because the project description file (.project) is out of sync with the file system.
```

Whatever that means.

When I cntrl-click the underlined error and try Quick Fix it offers me "resolve dependencies" which sounds promising, but after a few seconds, it comes back and informs me that

```dart
Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies... (15.3s)
Could not find package command_line_app at https://pub.dartlang.org.
Depended on by:
- web_application 0.0.0
```

I hope this is clear-er and gives a better insight into both what I'm trying to do and what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
you need to add

```
dependencies:
  command_line_app:
    path: ../command_line_app
```

to your dependencies in `web_application/pubspec.yaml`.

**EDIT END**

When you want to make code reusable in different packages, you should put that code into the `lib` directory of that package and import it using `import 'package:mypackage/myfile.dart';`.

Another problem you may face is, that browser applications can't import packages that have a `dart:io` dependency. If you want to reuse code between command line and browser applications you should move them into the lib directory of another package `my_shared_code` where you put only code that doesn't depend on `dart:io` (for example some entity classes) and import this code from both app packages (browser and command line).

Comment: Gunter, Thanks; this is the right direction, but I'm still confused: I have the following directories: command-line-project/bin/myfile.dart That's where the Dart Editor created it. Do I have to copy the file to some other directory (a Lib directory?) if so, where would I create that? I'm not using dart.io yet, so that's not the issue.

Comment: You should leave the entry file (containing `main()`) in the `bin` directory, and create the files with the classes you want to use in different packages in the `yourpackage/lib/yourshared.dart` directory.
In your entry file in `bin` you can import it like `import package:yourpackage/yourshared.dart';` 
Note the missing `lib` in the import path. This is added automatically, therefore you can only import files from the `lib` directory. Relative paths work only inside the same package.

Comment: Okay -- getting closer. I could not make /lib work. I created a /lib directory by hand and copied the files into it. Failed. However, I dragged and dropped them into the /packages directory and now inside *that* project, I can do import "package:myfile.dart"; and it works. However: inside my other project, I still can't seem to find them. I tried import: "package:ProjectName/myfile.dart"; and that fails. I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly remedial, but I don't know what it is....

Comment: You shouldn't do anything with the packages directory. This is maintained by the `pub` tool. If you do something manually this will cause troubles without doubt. Can you describe your package structure better in your question, then it's easier to make suggestions what should be changed, and how. There are also many Dart projects at github where you can take a look. I have some projects with a similar dependency structure at https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_utils, https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_utils_server, https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_utils_browser. This projects are still very small.

Comment: Gunter, I updated my post to show my directory structure and looked at your examples (I also re-read the Dart documentation about directory layout). To my read, I'm following the rules -- and since they work _within_ a project, I think that's probably right. I think there must be something I need to do to make it work _across_ projects, but I can't figure out what. Thanks for your help and your patience.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you! Oddly, command_line_app **was** in the dependency file, but without the path information. I added that manually, and it works fine. I wonder why it couldn't / didn't auto-generate... is that something I'm supposed to do by hand, or is there some Dart Editor functionality that's not working right in my install?  Not a big deal either way. THANKS!

Comment: By default dependencies are looked up at pub.dartlang.org. A path dependency is a deviation of the default and must be configured explicitely.